# Is this idiomatic usage of 'daylight' and 'with'?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

In a recent [Washington Post article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/powerpost/paloma/daily-202/2018/03/29/daily-202-loyalty-to-trump-emerges-as-a-top-issue-in-republican-primary-campaign-commercials/5abc494530fb042a378a2f32/?utm_term=.99f6f278db10), one finds the following sentence (the underlining is mine):

> GOP candidates are stepping up attacks on their rivals over any d̲a̲y̲l̲i̲g̲h̲t̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲y̲’̲v̲e̲ ̲s̲h̲o̲w̲n̲ ̲w̲i̲t̲h̲ ̲T̲r̲u̲m̲p̲.

The OED does record a similar phrase, with the meaning 'a perceptible difference or distinction between one person or thing and another'. But all the examples there have *daylight between [two things]* rather than *daylight with [one thing]*:

> This drawing the line between professional and amateur sports is getting to the point that it is pretty difficult to see d̲a̲y̲l̲i̲g̲h̲t̲ ̲b̲e̲t̲w̲e̲e̲n̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲m̲.
>
> In a two-hour interview with the staff of the New York Times, he sought very skillfully to suggest that there was clear d̲a̲y̲l̲i̲g̲h̲t̲ ̲b̲e̲t̲w̲e̲e̲n̲ ̲h̲i̲s̲ ̲p̲o̲s̲i̲t̲i̲o̲n̲ ̲a̲n̲d̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲P̲r̲e̲s̲i̲d̲e̲n̲t̲'̲s̲.
>
> Shatner may have been his predecessor in Star Trek, but he likes to think there's a fair amount of d̲a̲y̲l̲i̲g̲h̲t̲ ̲b̲e̲t̲w̲e̲e̲n̲ ̲h̲i̲s̲ ̲t̲a̲l̲e̲n̲t̲ ̲a̲n̲d̲ ̲S̲h̲a̲t̲n̲e̲r̲'̲s̲.

On google books, it was easy to find other examples of usage like that recorded in the OED (e.g. [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=aAXqCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT41&dq=%22daylight%20between%22&pg=PT41#v=onepage&q=%22daylight%20between%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=JSxnAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA75&dq=%22daylight%20between%22&pg=PA75#v=onepage&q=%22daylight%20between%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=FGu5V3_xjxQC&lpg=PA193&dq=%22daylight%20between%22&pg=PA193#v=onepage&q=%22daylight%20between%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=xE1hBBF37kwC&lpg=PT416&dq=%22daylight%20between%22&pg=PT416#v=onepage&q=%22daylight%20between%22&f=false),... ). On the other hand, I have been unable to find any examples of usage like that in the Washington Post article. As best as I can tell, what the author should have written there is *any daylight they've shown b̲e̲t̲w̲e̲e̲n̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲m̲s̲e̲l̲v̲e̲s̲ ̲a̲n̲d̲ ̲T̲r̲u̲m̲p̲*.

Does anyone know if the usage in Washington Post is attested in other sources? Or is it an invention by the author of that article?

Comment: **With** can have the sense of **concerning** or **in the case of** and your question is a good example for that. I would not say that this is idiomatic. It belongs to the normal use of 'with'. Check [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/with?q=with)

Answer (score 1):

The context is key here

> Fealty to Trump has become more of a litmus test than ever for
>   Republicans. Emboldened by private polling and focus groups that show
>   the president is incredibly popular with the base, GOP candidates are
>   stepping up attacks on their rivals over any daylight they’ve shown
>   with Trump, even if it stemmed from his personal conduct toward women
>   or apostasy on traditional conservative orthodoxy. It’s another
>   illustration of the degree to which Trumpism has come to define the
>   Republican Party.

References to 'Fealty to Trump' and 'Trumpism' make it clear that 'showing daylight' means "showing daylight between."  I don't think one could use the phrase on it's own without such context.

Answer (score 1):

**daylight between**  [MW Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/daylight%20between)

> distance or difference between (people or things)

As between 'rivals' and 'Trump'.

The use of *daylight between* is frequent.  I hear it often used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I have never suggested that *daylight b͟e͟t͟w͟e͟e͟n͟ ͟X͟ ͟a͟n͟d͟ ͟Y͟* was an invention. That construction, as I've said in my post, is well attested both in the OED and in google books. Rather, my question was explicitly about *daylight w͟i͟t͟h͟ ͟X͟*, for which I couldn't find any attested examples.